# How to align custom UINavigationBar title (UILabel )in middle (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel, uinavigationbar

I am using following code to align 2 strings in UINavigationBar centre .

for ex:

```
         <Back     John Kelly Maria
                       23/F
```

I need these kind of middle aligned text in UINavigationbar but what jam now getting is all the text aligned in right side of UINavigationBar .
 something like this

```
      <Back                  John Kelly Maria   
                                  23/F
```

Please help..me .
this is my code

```
 UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,50)];

    UIFont * customFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:19]; //custom font
    NSString * text =title;
    UILabel *patientNameLabel;
    if([title length]>15){
        patientNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320,30)];
    }else{
        patientNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320,30)];

    }
    patientNameLabel.text = @"John Kelly Maria";
    patientNameLabel.font = customFont;
    patientNameLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    patientNameLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    patientNameLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 10.0f/12.0f;
    patientNameLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
    patientNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    patientNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    patientNameLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    NSString *subTitle =subTitleText;
    UIFont * customFont1 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14]; //custom font

    UILabel *subTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,25,320,20)];
    subTitleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    subTitleLabel.text = @"23/F";
    subTitleLabel.font = customFont1;
     subTitleLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    subTitleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;

    subTitleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    subTitleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 10.0f/12.0f;
    subTitleLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
    subTitleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    subTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [titleView addSubview:patientNameLabel];
    [titleView addSubview:subTitleLabel];
```

Comment: can you put screenshots what you exactly getting, it will more helpful in answering your question.

Comment: ok sure..i will add link of screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below two lines before addSubview lines..

```
patientNameLabel.center = CGPointMake(titleView.frame.size.width/2, 0);
subTitleLabel.center = CGPointMake(titleView.frame.size.width/2, 25);
```

Add Below Code & see

```
UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,50)];

UIFont * customFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:19]; //custom font
NSString * text =@"Nilesh Patel";
UILabel *patientNameLabel;
if([text length]>15){
    patientNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320,30)];
}else{
    patientNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320,30)];

}
patientNameLabel.text = @"Nilesh Patel";
patientNameLabel.font = customFont;
patientNameLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
patientNameLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
patientNameLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 10.0f/12.0f;
patientNameLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
patientNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
patientNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
patientNameLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
NSString *subTitle =@"iOS Developer";
UIFont * customFont1 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14]; //custom font

UILabel *subTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,25,320,20)];
subTitleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

subTitleLabel.text = @"28/M";
subTitleLabel.font = customFont1;
subTitleLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
subTitleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;

subTitleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
subTitleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 10.0f/12.0f;
subTitleLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
subTitleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
subTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

patientNameLabel.center = CGPointMake(titleView.frame.size.width/2, 10);
subTitleLabel.center = CGPointMake(titleView.frame.size.width/2, 30);


[titleView addSubview:patientNameLabel];
[titleView addSubview:subTitleLabel];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:titleView];
```

**Note : You have set static frame to titleView so if you see your app on different device you will not be able to see the text in exact centre. To avoid this set the titleView frame dynamically based on device/view width.**

Comment: it moved to right top (parentNameLabel colliding with status bar)  corner...not working the way i want

Comment: Add 10 pixel to Y postion..  Like.. patientNameLabel.center = CGPointMake(titleView.frame.size.width/2, 10);
subTitleLabel.center = CGPointMake(titleView.frame.size.width/2, 35);

Comment: Right corner mean? Which image I have to refers on your original post?

Comment: Do one thing.. centre the title view as well. Like     titleView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, 10);

Comment: iam uploading link of screenshot

Comment: How you are adding titleView on navigation bar?

Comment: I just updated my answer & added a required code.. Please replace your code with my code & see the result..

Comment: your code also appearing in same way...right side corner

Comment: ok.this line is the culprit..." self.navigationItem.titleView =titleview" instead of adding as subview..now coming correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try Frame setting like this

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,20,screenWidth,50)];
UILabel *subTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,25,screenWidth,20)];
UILabel *patientNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,screenWidth,30)];
```